# Can I log out a specific user using the azure ad api or adal-anuglar?

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I'm working on a MEAN stack web app which uses the adal-angular library to manage our azure ad user sessions.

Right now, when a user clicks log out, they are sent to the Azure sign out page where they can choose out of all logged in sessions which session to log out of.

But I want to automatically log out the user that is clicking log out, instead of asking them who they want to log out.

Can this be set up in adal or through a specific azure ad api configuration?

This is the current adal configuration in the app file.

```
adalProvider.init(<adal.Config>{
                tenant: <redacted>,
                clientId: <redacted>,
                anonymousEndpoints: <redacted>,
                redirectUri: <redacted>',
                postLogoutRedirectUri: <redacted>,
                popUp: <redacted>,
                extraQueryParameter: <redacted>
                },
                $httpProvider
            );
```

and this is the logout method in the controller

```
this.adalService.logOut();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no ADAL supported method to logout specific users. The only way to do this is if you keep track of the access tokens from the cache and when a user is interested in logging out, you would clear the cache of that specific user's token.

Please see : [Adal JS - Logout of just one AD site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55954862/adal-js-logout-of-just-one-ad-site/56228682#56228682) for more info on manually logging users out.

Comment: this is what i feared after poring over the documentation. thank you for the clarification.